# How do I create a colour histogram of a custom colour palette in OpenCV?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I have an image:

[image]

and the range of colours in the image is generated as the linear interpolation through these RGB values:

```
rgb = [165,0,38], w = 0.0
rgb = [222,63,46], w = 0.125 
rgb = [248,142,82], w = 0.25
rgb = [253,212,129], ...
rgb = [254,254,189]
rgb = [203,232,129]
rgb = [132,202,102]
rgb = [42,159,84]
rgb = [0,104,55], w = 1.0
```

How can I create a graph/histogram where the x-axis is the range of colours and the value is the percentage of the image with that colour of pixel.

Comment: Your color scale looks a scaled version of the Hue channel in an HSV image.

Comment: Does your `x-axis` **have** to vary in accordance with those colours?  For example, could you perhaps start from green, go towards red, then end at orange/white?

Comment: @rayryeng I guess the actual order of the x-axis is not important at this point. Once I find out how the colour scale is ordered and I just sort the columns.

Comment: @beaker the colour scale is a linear gradient between the red and the green.

Comment: I added more detail on the colour scale in the edit @beaker

Comment: Well red to green on the Hue scale is from `0` to `120` degrees...

Comment: Unfortunately the updated values don't line up very well so another approach is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rather brute force attempt with how I would solve this problem.  Mind you, I'm finding colour distances in the RGB space but it is well known that colour distances in RGB do not mimic human perception of colours very well... but this is something to get you started.  Be advised that you need [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) and [`matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.org/) installed.  `matplotlib` is to allow for plotting the histogram as a stem plot.

Basically, those RGB values that you have defined we can consider as **keypoints**.  From here, we need to define the total number of bins in the histogram that we would need to compute.  I set this to 64 to start.  What you need to do first is interpolate the red, green and blue values for those values that you have defined so that we can create a RGB lookup table.  As such, we would need to generate 64 RGB values from the beginning RGB tuple to the ending RGB tuple, using those keypoints that you have defined and we will linearly interpolate those RGB values.

This RGB lookup table will be a 64 x 3 array and the basic algorithm is to extract a RGB pixel from your image and determine the **closest** pixel to the lookup table from this pixel.  We find this index that produces the minimum distance and we would increment the corresponding bin in the histogram.  I compute this by the Euclidean distance squared.  There's no point in taking the square root to get the Euclidean distance as we want to find the minimum distance.  Square rooting each term won't change which pixel colour is closest to which entry in the lookup table.  We would repeat this for the rest of the pixels in the image.

To compute the minimum distance, use [`numpy.sum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) as well as subtracting each pixel you get in the input image with each location in the lookup table via [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).  We square each of the distances, sum them up, then determine the location in the lookup table that gives us the minimum by [`numpy.argmin`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html).

Now, in order to create the interpolated RGB lookup, I called [`numpy.interp`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) on the red, green and blue channel keypoints where the output (`y`) values are from those keypoint values for the red, green and blue values you defined, and the input (`x`) values are **dummy** input values that are linearly increasing from 0 up to as many control points as we have subtracted by 1.  So our input `x` keypoints are:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, ..., N-1]
```

`N` is the total number of keypoints, and the output keypoints are the red, green and blue keypoint values respectively.  In order to create a lookup of 64 values, we would need to create 64 points between `0` to `N-1`, and we can achieve this with [`numpy.linspace`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html).

Now one intricacy with OpenCV is that images are read in BGR format.  As such, I **flipped** the channels so that they are RGB, and I also cast the image as `float32` so that we can maintain the precision when calculating the distances.  Also, once I calculate the histogram, because you want **percentages**, I convert the histogram into percentages by dividing by the total number of values in the histogram (which is the number of pixels in the image) and multiply by 100% to get this in percentage.

Without further ado, here's my attempt in code.  Your image looks like a wheat field, and so I called your image `wheat.png`, but rename it to whatever your image is called:

```
import numpy as np # Import relevant libraries
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read in image    
img = cv2.imread('wheat.png')

# Flip the channels as the image is in BGR and cast to float
img = img[:,:,::-1].astype('float32')

# control points for RGB - defined by you
rgb_lookup = np.array([[165,0,38], [222,63,46], [248,142,82],
                      [253,212,129], [254,254,189], [203,232,129],
                      [132,202,102], [42,159,84], [0,104,55]])

# Define number of bins for histogram
num_bins = 64

# Define dummy x keypoint values
x_keypt = np.arange(rgb_lookup.shape[0])

# Define interpolating x values
xp = np.linspace(x_keypt[0], x_keypt[-1], num_bins)

# Define lookup tables for red, green and blue
red_lookup = np.interp(xp, x_keypt, rgb_lookup[:,0])
green_lookup = np.interp(xp, x_keypt, rgb_lookup[:,1])
blue_lookup = np.interp(xp, x_keypt, rgb_lookup[:,2])

# Define final RGB lookup
rgb_final_lookup = np.column_stack([red_lookup, green_lookup, blue_lookup])

# Brute force
# For each pixel we have in our image, find the closest RGB distance
# from this pixel to each pixel in our lookup.  Find the argmin,
# then log into histogram accordingly
hist = np.zeros(num_bins)

# Get the rows and columns of the image
rows = img.shape[0]
cols = img.shape[1]

# For each pixel
for i in np.arange(rows):
  for j in np.arange(cols):
    # Get colour pixel value
    val = img[i,j,:]

    # Find closest distance to lookup
    dists = np.sum((rgb_final_lookup - val)**2.0, axis=1)

    # Get location for histogram
    ind = np.argmin(dists)

    # Increment histogram
    hist[ind] += 1

# Get percentage calculation
hist = 100*hist / (rows*cols)

# Plot histogram
plt.stem(np.arange(num_bins), hist)
plt.title('Histogram of colours')
plt.xlabel('Bin number')
plt.ylabel('Percentage')
plt.show()
```

---

The graph we get is:

[image]

The above figure makes sense.  At the beginning of your colour spectrum, there are a lot of red and yellowish pixels, which are defined near the beginning of your spectrum.  The green and whitish pixels are more towards the end and don't comprise of most of the pixels.  You'll need to play around with the number of bins to get this working to your tastes.

Good luck!