# What is missing for a better MATLAB Plot3 visualization?

Tags: matlab, visualization, data-visualization, mplot3d

I have produced the following figure using MATLAB `plot3` function.

[image]

This figure is not good.
Because, I think, it's too hard for readers to estimate the coordinates from this figure.
Points height (Z value) is too hard to be estimated from the figure.
What is missing in my figure that makes it hard to be interpreted ?

---

To Play with the data:
The visualized data is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw1wxZHj3VakY1BmdkVLcUdlelk/view?usp=sharing). The function to produce my current figure is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw1wxZHj3VakNFRTZ0NrN2JWN28/view?usp=sharing). Either comment the mArrow3 call, or download it from [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25372-marrow3-m-easy-to-use-3d-arrow).

Comment: could you provide sample data that we can play with?

Comment: @Benoit_11 I have added the data to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[kkuilla's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29349336/produce-a-3d-stem-plot-with-a-custom-colormap-in-matlab/29357396#29357396) about heat map produced a much better result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To better see height you can use [`stem3`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stem3.html) to **draw a vertical line** from the floor to each point. You can enhance the representation with a semi-transparent [`patch`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html) at zero height to **highlight the floor**.

```
% // Random data
x = -20+50*rand(1,50);
y = 150*rand(1,50);
z = -5+10*rand(1,50);

%// With plot
figure
plot3(x,y,z,'.','markersize',8)
grid on
axis equal
view(-33, 14)

%// With stem3 and patch
figure
stem3(x,y,z,'.','markersize',8)
grid on
hold on
patch([-20 30 30 -20], [0 0 150 150], [0 0 0 0], 'k', ...
    'edgecolor', [.5 .5 .5], 'FaceAlpha' , .1)
axis equal
view(-33, 14)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: nice! I borrowed your "dummy data" hope you don't mind!

Comment: @Benoit_11 Of course not! I usually do that from others too :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be intrinsic to these kind of plots: the 0d dots of your data are hard to interpret perspectivically, your brain can't decypher at which *depth* the data points are located. For instance, it would seem to me that you have no data poinst above z=0 and above x=15, which is obviously wrong, but my brain attributes most of your points to the z=-5 plane.

Unless your data points have finite volume which proportionally changes with distance (which can not be done with matlab, and probably wouldn't help much anyway), you might want to reconsider your way of visualization. How about having 3 plots, one each with camera along the x, y, and z axes?

**EDIT**: the [suggestion of Luis Mendo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31541696/5067311) makes me think I should probably have a more open mind when trying to answer a question:)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use different colors/markers/point size to discriminate between various regions in your data. For instance values having `z` below 0 are red and those above are green. Here is a simple example using `scatter3` with 4 distinct regions. Thanks to Luis Mendo for the dummy data.

```
clc;clear;close all


% // Random data...thanks Luis Mendo
x = -20+50*rand(1,50);
y = 150*rand(1,50);
z = -5+10*rand(1,50);

%// Get indices for various regions in your data
region1 = find(z>=-4 & z<-2);
region2 = find(z>=-2 & z<0);
region3 = find(z>=0 & z<2);
region4 = find(z>=2 & z<4);

%// Draw each region with its own color/size
scatter3(x(region1),y(region1),z(region1),20,'r','filled')
hold on
scatter3(x(region2),y(region2),z(region2),40,'y','*')
scatter3(x(region3),y(region3),z(region3),60,'g','filled')
scatter3(x(region4),y(region4),z(region4),80,'b')

grid on

view(-33, 14)
```

[image]

Comment: Good idea, I actually thought about it but I wanted to create a heat map. So, the dot color is proportional to the dot Z value. But I failed.

Comment: Sure! Of course you could automate all the region selection thing so that you don't enter them manually.

Comment: I've found a good answer for the heat map: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29349336/produce-a-3d-stem-plot-with-a-custom-colormap-in-matlab/29357396#29357396).
But I will keep the question not answered for now to hear maybe better thoughts.

Comment: Yes the answers really look very good!